# Ruby/Appium: How to select element from find_elements array via text attribute

Tags: arrays, ruby, find, appium, element

So I use a general "I press "*" button" Gherkin statement for pressing buttons. My problem is the text is not standardized throughout the app.

What I want to do is use find_elements to form an array of all button elements, take the text from my Gherkin input (for example: 'I press the "Yes" button'), utilize the .casecmp method to ignore the capitalization of my button text from the find_elements array and compare the text attributes and my Gherkin input.

Here's my attempt at the code:

```
Then (/^I press the "([^"]*)" button$/) do |button_text|
#assign gherkin input to variable
@button_text = button_text
#create find_elements array for all Buttons
button_array = find_elements(xpath: "//android.widget.Button")
#create for loop that will compare each element's text with @button_text
  button_array.each do |index|
   #Attempting to reference text attribute of array at index and compare @button_text with case insensitive comparison

   matching_button = button_array[index].text.casecmp("#{@button_text}")
     if matching_button = 0 #this means it's a match
      button_array[index].click()
     else
     end 
  end
end
```

At the moment I get the following errors:

```
And I press the "YES" button                  # features/step_definitions_android/common_steps.rb:107
      no implicit conversion of Selenium::WebDriver::Element into Integer (TypeError)
      ./features/step_definitions_android/common_steps.rb:113:in `[]'
      ./features/step_definitions_android/common_steps.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
      ./features/step_definitions_android/common_steps.rb:111:in `each'
      ./features/step_definitions_android/common_steps.rb:111:in `/^I press the "([^"]*)" button$/'
      features/FAB.feature:18:in `And I press the "YES" button'
```

I'm not totally sure what these errors mean in my case but I'm continuing my research. If anyone can share insight into what I'm doing incorrectly I'd greatly appreciate it.

Also is there any documentation as to how appium stores elements in that array? Can I even compare the text attribute of the element to a variable or other value? Thanks a ton for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index which you have taken will have the web-element instead of an Integer which you are expecting. Try the following :

```
Then (/^I press the "([^"]*)" button$/) do |button_text|
  button_array = find_elements(xpath: "//android.widget.Button")
  button_array.each do |btn|
     btn.click if btn.text == button_text
  end
end
```

Let me know in the comments if you face further issue.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks! For my case I had to add the caseless comparison to address my casing problem as follows:

button_array.each do |btn|
    btn.click if btn.text.casecmp("#{button_text}") == 0
  end

Otherwise this is perfect for what I need, thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad this could help, another option if u don't bother about case if you can convert both into lower or uppercase and compare, here is how you do that...
btn.text.downcase == button_text.downcase

Happy to help!!